# Serialize/Deserialize two-dimensional array

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, serialization

For some reason my previous question was considered too vague. So let me be more specific.

I have a 2 dimensional array of type single.
I want to serialize it to save in an Access database.

The suggestion was to save it as a Memo field which is fine.
I want to later read the Memo field and deserialize it to retrieve the original array.
I have searched extensively on the web and here and can not find the answer. I believe I am serializing the array correctly but do not know how to deserialize it.

This code appears to work for serializing but I can not figure out how to deserialize:

```
Dim f As New System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter  
Dim ms As New MemoryStream  
f.Serialize(ms, arLHS)  
Dim byArr As Byte() = ms.ToArray
```

I then save byArr to the Memo field.

Please provide sample code.

Comment: Your previous question was indeed rather vague. People on SO tend to frown at the lack of detail. This question is well-phrased. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can deserialize it via base64 converter:

```
Dim str_b64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(byArr)
Dim ms2 As New MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(str_b64))
Dim intArr2(,) As Int32 = f.Deserialize(ms2)
```

This may look somewhat awkward, but it works - tested in a console app in VS 2010.

Credit goes [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/100732-serializingdeserializing-a-2-dimensional-array/). Through this link, you can also find the full version of the code to play with.

Comment: I tried the following code but get an error  Unable to cast object of type System.String to type System.Byte[]  This occurs when doing Convert.ToBase64String in the following code:  Dim f As New System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter

Dim ms As New MemoryStream
f.Serialize(ms, arLHS)

Dim byArr As Byte() = ms.ToArray

Comment: Sorry, I pasted wrong code. Here is correct code (and .Item("LHS") is saved as Memo field in Access):  Dim theArrayAsString As String = Convert.ToBase64String(dtLHS.Rows(0).Item("LHS"))

Dim ms2 As New MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(theArrayAsString))

Dim newLHS(,) As Single = f.Deserialize(ms2)

Comment: @JohnLee: Unfortunately, you cannot format the code in comments. So please update your original question. Did you try the full code version from the link I mentioned? There may be discrepancies between that and your version in serializing the value, as you have to be using matching serialize/deserialize method.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did see that link previously when searching for a solution. Yours was correct but I think the problem was in saving the serialized data as a Memo which is a string that could not be cast as byte array. When I changed the field type to OLEObject in Access it appears to work. Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the data type of the Access field from Memo to OLE Object and that seems to work. When I look at the data in Access it tells me the field is "Long binary data" and I was able to use the following code after reading the record from Access:

`Dim f As New System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.BinaryFormatter

    Dim byArr As Byte()

    byArr = DirectCast(dtLHS.Rows(0).Item("LHS"), Byte())

    Dim theArrayAsString As String = Convert.ToBase64String(byArr)

    Dim ms2 As New MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(theArrayAsString))

    Dim newLHS(,) as single = f.Deserialize(ms2)`

Is this correct?

Comment: On StackOverflow it's uncommon to ask questions in the answers. I understand this is directly related to the question, but please take care to create another question for that. You are more likely to get answers this way as well.

Comment: Hi Neolisk, I appreciate your input on how to be a good member of Stackoverflow. I do want to follow the correct etiquette. I asked a new question because I could not see how to format a comment reply containing code. Can you point me to instructions on how to do that?

Comment: Your original question is how to `Serialize/Deserialize two-dimensional array`, which I tried to cover in my answer. Database side of it is a related in your case, but generally a different question. Use `Ask Question` feature in the top right corner of every page, and in that other question be specific about your problem with database types. From your post above, it not clear to me what `Is this correct?` is referring to, so please elaborate on that in your new question. Thanks!