# Storing array in XML/reading it with LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, linq

I am trying to get 2D array representing distances between specific cities using LINQ. It is up to me to pick proper XML representation of the problem. At first, I used MatLAB-style array to represent dependencies, which looked like this:

```
<cityMap>
      [-, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8; 
          1, -, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8;
          1, 2, -, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8;
          1, 2, 3, -, 5, 6, 7, 8;
          1, 2, 3, 4, -, 6, 7, 8;
          1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -, 7, 8;
          1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, -, 8;
          1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, -]
</cityMap>
```

It was very convenient to get this matrix from single LINQ query and parse it in C#, but from the XML point of view it was rather not correct (multiple data in one tag). Now I am trying something like this:

```
<salesman>
  <salesmanNumber>10</salesmanNumber>
  <cities>
    <city id="1">
      <headquarter>1</headquarter>
      <distance toCity="2">2</distance>
      <distance toCity="3">3</distance>
      <distance toCity="4">4</distance>
      <distance toCity="5">5</distance>
      <distance toCity="6">6</distance>
    </city>
    <city id="2">
      <headquarter>1</headquarter>
      <distance toCity="1">1</distance>
      <distance toCity="3">3</distance>
      <distance toCity="4">4</distance>
      <distance toCity="5">5</distance>
      <distance toCity="6">6</distance>
               [....]
  </cities>
</salesman>
```

And two questions emerge: 
 1. Is this correct form of representing an array?
 2. How to read this data with LINQ query so that I will be able to
    parse it to array?

Comment: See this question [Serialize/Deserialize two-dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282748/serialize-deserialize-two-dimensional-array).

Comment: There is nothing wrong by representing an array as an element value with comma separated values on multiple line too.  You just need to format/parse the value by using `string.Join()` and `string.Split()` methods

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be XML ? 2-D array maps more naturally to an excel file

Comment: Well, unfortunately XML was forced on me and I have no other options in this case.